# Getting child data in react nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am not sure how to get the nested object data in react jsx, can anyone help me?

```
wine:
{
_id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471815",
name: "Margaux",
wineType: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Red Wine" },
numberInStock: 5,
vintage: 1982,
volume: 750,
imageURL:
  "www.abc.come",
region: { _id: "2", name: "Bordeaux" },
price: 18000
},
```

I am looking for the name in region object,

I try testing {wine.region.name} but having error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Comment: I think it need to be `variableName.Wine.region.name`

Comment: In json you have defined `Wine` but you are accessing it will small letter `{wine.region.name}`

Comment: Put this object into an variable and then access using that variable.

Comment: may be its rendering issue means you are accessing data before initializing of object.

Comment: I can actually get data with {wine.name} and result in "Margaux",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U have to use the object as invariable so define `let data = {....}` or in JSON file `{ "data": {....} ,...}`.

```
let wine={
        _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471815",
        name: "Margaux",
        wineType: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Red Wine" },
        numberInStock: 5,
        vintage: 1982,
        volume: 750,
        imageURL:
          "www.abc.come",
        region: { _id: "2", name: "Bordeaux" },
        price: 18000
    }

    let {region:{name}}=wine;
    console.log('name',name);
```

> O/P : Bordeaux

Answer (score 1):

Your format of json is not looking correct please try this one

```
wine={
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471815",
    name: "Margaux",
    wineType: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Red Wine" },
    numberInStock: 5,
    vintage: 1982,
    volume: 750,
    imageURL:
      "www.abc.come",
    region: { _id: "2", name: "Bordeaux" },
    price: 18000
}
```

first assign the hole object in wine and then try to access like {wine.region.name} it will work. It seems like a wrong format of json.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the attachment your JSON is not valid and running it as it is throws error of invalid token thats why you are unable to go to the next nodes. The attachment also shows how to correctly use it and visit specific node in jason[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsVcU.png